# Loading a .csv file in d3.js inside django is not working

Tags: django, d3.js

I am trying to load a csv file inside django in javascript but it gives me an error: http://127.0.0.1:8000/data.csv is not found , the data.csv location is inside the templates folder with the html page.

My code:

```
    d3.csv("data.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
    for (var i = 1, n = columns.length; i < n; ++i)
             d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
             return d;
     }, function(error, data) {
       if (error) throw error;
       }
```

Comment: there is NO directory in the request for `http://127.0.0.1:8000/data.csv`, so it does not look in the templates folder

Comment: how to solve it?

Comment: understand how Django and HTTP works

Comment: Don't forget to read the official Django doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First You would need to look how Django server works and  to serve static file in Django [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial06/)**.

You can not just load static file as d3.csv("data.csv")

Then Follow these steps

**1.** Add Following in settings.py

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

**2.** Create static folder inside root project folder and add csv file inside static folder

**3.** The you need to serve static file and load

- {% load static %} at top
- {% static "data.csv" %}

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>hello d3</h1>
<div>
</div>
<script>
    d3.csv('{%  static 'data.csv' %}', function (err, csv) {
        console.log(csv)
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If your file is not static and user uploaded media file just replace d3.csv code as below.
And before this you need add MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT in settings as below

- settings.py

```py
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

- visualisation.html

```html
<script>
d3.csv('{{ object.file.url}}', function (err, csv) {
        console.log(csv)
    });
</script>
```