# How to load a csv file from static in django into javascript function

Tags: javascript, django, d3.js

I Have a javascript function in static/js and i want to get the data from a csv file available in static/csv.

My javascript code:

```
   function graph1(){
   d3.csv('{%  static 'csv/data2.csv' %}', function(error, data) {


  }
  }
```

Comment: I have answered in  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54960091/loading-a-csv-file-in-d3-js-inside-django-is-not-working/54961043#54961043)
. Have a look and let me know if it helps.

Comment: @bkawan the answer is for a script in an html file , i have a javascript file so the {% load  static %} don't work in js

Comment: you will import js in your template code and can try {% load static %}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try like this

Define data variable in django template filea and can be accessed in js file

Here the data variable in index.html is accessible in Javascript file

> index.html

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>hello d3</h1>
<div>
</div>
<script>
    var data = '{% static "data.csv" %}'
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/d3.js' %}">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> /static/js/d3.js

data varibale is passed from index.html

```
d3.csv(data, function (err, csv) {
    console.log(csv)
});
```